# How to add dependency for a PTransform based on PubsubIO or any other stage of pipeline in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to execute a certain piece of beam code once elements from my PCollection have been published to Pub/Sub, I'm using PubsubIO to write messages.

The next piece of code updates timestamp in a file and should only be executed once the publish operation completes.

Is there any way via which I can add this dependency, since beam starts the execution parallelly, the code updating the file gets updated even if stages before PubSubIO fail which subsequently means that records weren't published to Pub/Sub.

Is there any way to implement this interlocking of a PTransform(that updates the file) based on whether PubsubIO successfully executed or not?

Comment: I think you can do this with [Wait](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html), but only in Java for streaming pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Hitobat, I will test it out but is there anything similar for batch pipelines?

Comment: Not that I've found unfortunately. If you're running locally you can have 2 pipelines in same file, to do the different stages. But if you want dataflow template it's impossible for batch mode. You need multiple dataflow template for multiple pipeline stage.

Comment: Is there any java functionality by which I can achieve this?

Comment: From what I've been able to figure out, there is no Java functionality for this with PubSub IO yet. Some other IOs output a results transform for this functionality, but that hasn't been implemented in PubSubIO yet. Your best option seems to be what Hitobat suggested, to use a multi-stage pipeline to do this.